# Root complex and memory control hub

Tags: architecture, x86, pci

While I was reading about PCI express internals, I found that

ICH (IO Controller HUB) is south bridge.
My question is, I see it is connected to root complex up above. Also, in some other material, ICH is connected to Memory control hub (MCH) up above. Are root complex and MCH the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

> Are root complex and MCH the same thing?

Technically speaking, the answer is no (although in some platforms e.g. Santa Rosa, Montevina the root complex function resides on the MCH die)